# Error: concatUint8Array: Data must be in the form of a Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, openpgp.js

I am using Jest to test a small function of mine that makes use of OpenPGP.js https://openpgpjs.org/ (the latest version, 4.10.9).

I saw some workarounds using the library `text-encoding-utf-8` and I did this on my tests, but unfortunately, the error persists.

Even with:

```js
const textEncoding = await import("text-encoding-utf-8")
global.TextEncoder = textEncoding.TextEncoder
global.TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder
```

My function:

```js
import * as openpgp from "openpgp"

export async function decryptMessage(privateKeyArmored, passphrase, message) {
  const {
    keys: [privateKey],
  } = await openpgp.key.readArmored(privateKeyArmored)

  await privateKey.decrypt(passphrase)

  const { data } = await openpgp.decrypt({
    message: await openpgp.message.readArmored(message),
    privateKeys: [privateKey],
  })

  return data
}
```

And this is my test

```js
import * as openpgp from "openpgp"

import { decryptMessage } from "../src/crypto"

let privateKey
let publicKey

const passphrase = "password"

const oldTextEncoder = global.TextEncoder
const oldTextDecoder = global.TextDecoder

describe("crypto test suite", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    // workaround to openpgp works with jest
    const textEncoding = await import("text-encoding-utf-8")
    global.TextEncoder = textEncoding.TextEncoder
    global.TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder

    const { privateKeyArmored, publicKeyArmored } = await openpgp.generateKey({
      userIds: [{ name: "username" }],
      curve: "ed25519",
      passphrase,
    })

    privateKey = privateKeyArmored
    publicKey = publicKeyArmored
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    global.TextEncoder = oldTextEncoder
    global.TextDecoder = oldTextDecoder
  })

  test("decrypt message", async () => {
    const text = "test"

    const { data } = await openpgp.encrypt({
      message: openpgp.message.fromText(text),
      publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(publicKey)).keys,
    })

    const result = decryptMessage(privateKey, passphrase, data)

    expect(result).toBe(text)
  })
})
```

When I run, I got:

```sh
(node:10804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: concatUint8Array: Data must be in the form of a Uint8Array
(node:10804) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 25)
```

Any clues?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Do you have any conclusion about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the same issue and then I had to use a specific openpgp version. This is what ended up working for me:

```
"openpgp": "4.10.10",
"text-encoding-utf-8": "^1.0.2",
```

So, I had to use the proper functions inherent to this openpgp version as follows:

```
test('Encrypts a file using the GPG file', async () => {
    const textEncoding = await import("text-encoding-utf-8")
    global.TextEncoder = textEncoding.TextEncoder
    global.TextDecoder = textEncoding.TextDecoder


    const publicKey = fs.readFileSync('/path/file.asc')

    const input = fs.createReadStream('a.txt')

    const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
        message: await openpgp.message.fromBinary(input),
        publicKeys: (await openpgp.key.readArmored(publicKey)).keys,
    })
    console.log(encrypted)
```

Let me know if it works for you